# Memory Leak in VB.Net Desktop application

Tags: vb.net, memory-management, memory-leaks, desktop-application, out-of-memory

We have a problem with our vb.net desktop application memory usage. The application throws exception after usage of 4-5 hrs. We are checking this behavior using ANTS Memory Profiler, which shows continuous increases in private bytes. "Bytes in Heap" is reducing (it shows negative value between snapshots). The objects, variables and data elements are disposed in code.

The windows task manager shows working set of application around 12-20 MB (Which never increases above 100 MB) but commit size is starts from 95 MB and it throws error after reaching to approx. 400 MB while working remains to 40-60 MB max.

So the problem is with "Commit Size" which does not reduce substantially.

Our application is built in vb.net,sql server 2005, Infragistics Netadvantage controls 8.3 and framework 2.0. We are using web service as our middle tier. We also checked the same behavior after upgrading to VS 2012, Framework 4.5 and Infragistics Netadvantage controls 12.1.

Comment: "We have an app and the app has a memory problem" - maybe, but how shold somebody here be able to help? Most likely you app consists of more than 25 lines of code? It's more in the thousands lines of code? Somewhere in that thousands loc is your problem ... Such kind of problems usually are outside the scope of help from others by just seeing a brief problem description. I doubt that there is a "switch a to b" solution that fits your problem.

Comment: "It throws error" - what is the error?